# ElasticBeanstalk issue reading resource path - Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The error I am getting from the ElasticBeanstalk logs is:

> cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/keys/my-ssl.jks

I am requesting the file this way:

```
@Value("${javax.net.ssl.trustStore}")
private Resource trustStore;

@Value("${javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword}")
private char[] trustStorePassword;

@Value("${http.client.maxPoolSize}")
private Integer maxPoolSize;
```

My application.properties looks like:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:keys/my-ssl.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
http.client.maxPoolSize=10
```

My project structure looks like:

```
-src
 -main
  -resources
   -keys
    --my-ssl.jks
```

Note: this works locally perfectly, once deployed to EB it fails to find the jks.

Comment: Can you ssh into the EB instance and inspect from inside how your app is organized?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `ClassLoader` and `InputStream` together like so:

```
ClassLoader classLoaderKeyStore = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream keyStreamKeyStore = classLoaderKeyStore.getResourceAsStream("keys/my-ssl.jks");
```